# Why edit is disabled for the following question?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, specific-question

I am trying to edit following post but edit link is disabled.

[Bootstrap text box not stretching full width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22181636/bootstrap-text-box-not-stretching-full-width?answertab=active#tab-top)

[image]

Then I tried to go to other question to look weather they allow me to edit and seems all the other question I can edit it.

Its only this question that doesnt allow me to edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That question had a pending edit. While there are pending edits, the question cannot be edited. Locking the content is the reason why pending edits show up as an icon in the topbar - they need to be resolved quickly.

If you check, the edit was approved, and can now be edited.